# Is the GraphicsDevice.Clear call in XNA necessary in 3D?

Tags: xna, c#

It's a touch embarrassing to ask I think, but I've just never paid it any attention before and used it as I've seen in tutorials or the like in the past I believe.

Is there a need to use GraphicsDevice.Clear? 
If you don't use a skybox or similar, how do you change the "void" color from purple to something else?

I'm not seeing a way to change the backcolor or w/e you'd call it in 3D. I also can comment out the GraphicsDevice.Clear call I've always seemed to use and nothing seems to change.

Thanks!

Edit: With the code below, I still get a purple background:

```
    //Part of Game1.cs
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
        frameRate++;
        Map.ResortChunkPriority(Player);
        //GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.DepthBuffer | ClearOptions.Target, Color.White, 1f, 0);
        Map.Render(GraphicsDevice, clsResources.eTerrain, Player);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    //Map.Render call
    public void Render(GraphicsDevice device, Effect effect, clsEntity Player) {
        effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["MainTech"];
        effect.Parameters["VP"].SetValue(clsCamera.viewMatrix * clsResources.projectionMatrix);

        device.Indices = clsResources.indexBuffer;

        for (int i = 0; i < RenderQueue.Count; i++) {
            //if (RenderQueue[i].fDist > 10) continue;
            RenderQueue[i].Render(device, effect, Player.ChunkPosition);
        }
    }

    //RenderQueue's Render call
    public void Render(GraphicsDevice device, Effect effect, strVector2 CurrentChunk) {
        if (iGenState != 4) return;
        effect.Parameters["xOffset"].SetValue(CubeOffset.X);// + ChunkPos.X);
        effect.Parameters["zOffset"].SetValue(CubeOffset.Z);// + ChunkPos.Z);

        for (int i = 0; i < effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes.Count; i++) {
            effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[i].Apply();
            FaceStrips[0].Render(device, effect); FaceStrips[1].Render(device, effect);
            if (CurrentChunk.Z >= ChunkPos.Z) FaceStrips[2].Render(device, effect);
            if (CurrentChunk.Z <= ChunkPos.Z) FaceStrips[3].Render(device, effect);
            if (CurrentChunk.X <= ChunkPos.X) FaceStrips[4].Render(device, effect);
            if (CurrentChunk.X >= ChunkPos.X) FaceStrips[5].Render(device, effect);
        }
    }

    //FaceStrip's Render call
    public void Render(GraphicsDevice device, Effect effect) {
        if (iVertCounter == 0) return;

        for (int j = 0; j < geometryBuffer.Length; j++) {
            device.SetVertexBuffer(geometryBuffer[j]);
            device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, geometryBuffer[j].VertexCount, 0, geometryBuffer[j].VertexCount / 2);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try commenting out the clear call and making something move around the screen. You'll get a nice trail.

Comment: @Byte56 I added a screenshot above and am showing the code I currently use in my draw call. I do get a white background if I include ClearOptions.Target, but without any Clear call, I get purple as expected, yet do not get any trails. Perhaps the lack of trails is due to static terrain, but I wouldn't think that'd matter as you fly around with pixels at different depths changing. I think I (or the community thus far) is missing something.

Comment: Are you clearing it anywhere else in your code? You may be clearing it a second time when actually doing the draw.

Comment: The trails will appear where things aren't being cleared. so I would expect moving the camera up would leave trails at the border between the land and purple sky. But, it'll also depend on what else you have going on. You might not get trails like I describe.

Comment: I am not calling Clear on the graphicsdevice anywhere else. That I am sure of. @Byte56 I posted more code above to show more of what I'm doing in case it helps, but I didn't include my shader code as I wouldn't think it'd be helpful.  I do not see trails of any kind or any other artifacts. I understand the concept of clearing the buffer and became quite familiar with it in 2D, but I'm not (yet) seeing any negative results of ignoring it in 3D.

Comment: I feel like I should add, I'm not opposed to using it or anything, I'm just wanting to understand why to use it and why it doesn't seem to matter for me right now. If calling Clear on the graphicsdevice is the only thing that clears the depth buffer, I'd expect something like the trails Byte56 describes.

Comment: Extra info: The purple is the uninitialised surface colour. It is used instead of giving you garbage memory, to make it easier to find bugs. The reason you don't get trails (@Byte56) is because XNA (oddly enough) makes the surface uninitialised every time you swap the front buffer to the back buffer (ie: `Present`). Possibly for compatibility with mobile or Xbox. Possibly avoidable with `PreserveContents`. But your trails would flicker with double-buffering anyway - you'd want render targets. Finally: `GraphicsDevice.Clear` is a very fast operation.

Answer (score 3):

`GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);` would give you a white background color as an example.

This function clears the backbuffer, z buffer, and stencil buffer. It is recommended that you call this before doing any rendering in a given frame. You'll likely run into some weird rendering issues by not clearing the buffer, but you might not see any direct changes depending on your rendering setup.

tl;dr just keep it.

Comment: +1 - it's not just the obvious effect; the hardware depends on the function to return itself to a reliable internal state.  This is API agnostic, not just XNA or DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not call GraphicsDevice.Clear, whatever you drew last frame will draw again next frame and so on and so on. the screen will just be overdrawn with new stuff without the previous drawn stuff removed.

Comment: Except that XNA has a habit of clearing the backbuffer to "uninitialised purple" after a swap operation.